# Google App Engine SQL connection SQL issue (python)

Tags: python, sql, google-cloud-platform

This is my first python project deployed on Google Cloud. I have python script on App Engine and SQL database and have a problem to connect it.

main.py

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqlconnector://root:<password>@/timesheetdb?charset=utf8&unix_socket=/cloudsql/<Instance connection name>")
conn = engine.connect()
conn.close()

engine.dispose()
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: python37
```

requirements.txt

```
sqlalchemy
mysql-connector-python
```

I spent more than ten hours by searching for a solution, but still having a problem with the db connection. The latest state is:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'timesheetdb'
```

I guess, it will be some simple stupid error, but I have no idea how to continue.

Comment: 1) What is the database name? 2)I don't recommend specifying the database name in the connection string. Select the database after the connection so minimize the types of connection problems.

Comment: What John said. Confirm that you can connect without the db name. It may also be a permissions issue. Are you sure your IAM permissions for the service account App Engine has the right permissions. You need to have `Cloud SQL Client` assigned. If you haven't configured it, the service account will be the default service account: `service-PROJECT_NUMBER@gae-api-prod.google.com.iam.gserviceaccount.com`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Confirm the Data Base name.
2. Confirm you have enough permissions. Ensure that the service account for your service has one of the following IAM roles:

`Cloud SQL Client` (preferred)

`Cloud SQL Editor`

`Cloud SQL Admin`

3. Confirm your instance connection name:
   ProjectID:Location:DBName

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine) you can find the full explanation of connecting App Engine with CloudSQL My SQL. [Here the code example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/cloud-sql/mysql/sqlalchemy/main.py) in Pyhton.